# avx three operands for sqrt?

Tags: assembly, x86, simd, instructions, avx

Why has the avx sqrt (non-packed) instruction three operands?

```
vsqrtsd xmm1, xmm2, xmm3
```

Does this mean something like `xmm1=xmm2=sqrt(xmm3)`?

**Edit:** Detailed answer below but in short the assembly line means:

```
xmm1.low  = sqrt(xmm3.low);
xmm1.high = xmm2.high;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual*, Volume 2B, Page 4-407, "SQRTSD—Compute Square Root of Scalar Double-Precision Floating-
Point Value":

> **VSQRTSD xmm1, xmm2, xmm3/m64**
>
> Computes square root of the low double-precision floating point value in xmm3/m64 and stores the results in xmm1*. Also, upper double precision floating-point value (bits[127:64])
>   from xmm2 is copied to xmm1[127:64].
>
> **Operation**
>
> ```
> DEST[63:0] ← SQRT(SRC2[63:0])
> DEST[127:64] ← SRC1[127:64]
> DEST[VLMAX-1:128] ← 0
> ```

The instruction is simply following the pattern of other *binary* `V___SD` and `V___SS` operations like `VSUBSD`, which performs

```
DEST[63:0] ← SRC1[63:0] - SRC2[63:0]
DEST[127:64] ← SRC1[127:64]
DEST[VLMAX-1:128] ← 0
```

and like `VRCPSS xmm1, xmm2, xmm3/32`, which performs

```
DEST[31:0] ← APPROXIMATE(1/SRC2[31:0])
DEST[127:32] ← SRC1[127:32]
DEST[VLMAX-1:128] ← 0
```

The general form is like

```
xmm1.low = f(xmm2.low, xmm3.low);
xmm1.high = xmm2.high,
```

as described in *Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Software Developer’s Manual*, Volume 1, §11.4.1 "Packed and Scalar Double-Precision Floating-Point Instructions". For VSQRTSD we just define f(x, y) = √y, ignoring the first operand.

---

*: Note: The Intel Manual writes "xmm2" here, which is an error.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! But shouldn't the first sentence be: ... and stores the results in xmm1?